# Avoid duplicated event handlers?

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling

How do I avoid an event from being handled twice (if is the same handler?)

```
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim item As New Item
    AddHandler item.TitleChanged, AddressOf Item_TitleChanged
    AddHandler item.TitleChanged, AddressOf Item_TitleChanged

    item.Title = "asdf"

    Stop
  End Sub
  Private Sub Item_TitleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("Title changed!")
  End Sub
End Module

Public Class Item
  Private m_Title As String
  Public Property Title() As String
    Get
      Return m_Title
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      m_Title = value
      RaiseEvent TitleChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Event TitleChanged As EventHandler
End Class
```

Output:

```
Title changed!
Title changed!
```

Desired output:

```
Title changed!
```

I want the event manager to detect that this event is already handled by this handler and so it shouldn't rehandle (or readd) it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the event handler list in a `HashSet` will make sure the handlers are not duplicate references, the following snippet replacement for the question's `Item` class will work under the above sample (it won't re-add the handler if it's already in the `HashSet`):

```
Public Class Item
  Private m_Title As String
  Public Property Title() As String
    Get
      Return m_Title
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      m_Title = value
      RaiseEvent TitleChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Set
  End Property

  Private handlers As New HashSet(Of EventHandler)

  Public Custom Event TitleChanged As EventHandler
    AddHandler(value As EventHandler)
      handlers.Add(value)
    End AddHandler

    RemoveHandler(value As EventHandler)
      handlers.Remove(value)
    End RemoveHandler

    RaiseEvent(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
      For Each handler In handlers.Where(Function(h) h IsNot Nothing)
        handler(sender, e)
      Next
    End RaiseEvent
  End Event
End Class
```

Comment: This looks like memory leaks.

Answer (score 8):

You can also just always call `RemoveHandler` before `AddHandler`. I have found this  practical in specific scenarios.

Comment: Cuz it's prettu odd alway removing events before adding them. it looks kinda sloppy to me.

Comment: I agree it's a bit weird, but with the limited control over events, this is actually a very common way to do this as it's well-defined and elegant.

Comment: I actually upvoted for you answer, I am doubting if I should mark it as answer...